# How to place two algorithms side by side

Tags: minipage, algorithms, algorithm2e

I am using a document class called `informs` which can be accessed [here](https://pubsonline.informs.org/authorportal/latex-style-files) at `INFORMS Journal on Computing Style Files`.

I'd like to place two pseudocodes side by side. It looks like this question has been asked in different posts before, I have tried all the recommended solutions, but could not solve my problem.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[ijoc,nonblindrev]{informs3} % %current default for 
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII 
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,lined, noend]{algorithm2e}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[htbp]
      \SetAlFnt{\small}
      \DontPrintSemicolon
      \KwIn{Suppose we are given with several parameters} 
        \For{$i \in I$} {   }
      \caption{{\sc Animal microRNAs (miRNAs) regulate gene expression by 
                inhibiting.}}
   \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
   \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
  \begin{algorithm}[htbp]
  \SetAlFnt{\small}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \KwIn{Another set of inputs} 
  \For{$i \in I$} {}
  \caption{{\sc Here we show that a single miRNA can repress the production of 
         hundreds. }}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I am receiving undefined control sequence error. If I put the algorithms one by one without `minipage`, it works without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work with informs3, but I am too lazy to install it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,lined, noend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter{algocf}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{algorithm}[htbp]
      \SetAlFnt{\small}
      \DontPrintSemicolon
      \KwIn{Suppose we are given with several parameters} 
        \For{$i \in I$} {   }
      \caption{{\sc Animal microRNAs (miRNAs) regulate gene expression by 
                inhibiting.}}
   \end{algorithm}
\switchcolumn
  \begin{algorithm}[htbp]
  \SetAlFnt{\small}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \KwIn{Another set of inputs} 
  \For{$i \in I$} {}
  \caption{{\sc Here we show that a single miRNA can repress the production of 
         hundreds. }}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `algorithm` environment from `algorithm2e` is, by default, a floating environment, and therefore it cannot be placed inside of a `minipage` environment. Using the `[H]` placement specifier allows to prevent this; with this option the `algorithm` will not be a float anymore, and the `algorithm` could be placed in a `minipage`.

The following example outputs both algorithms side by side.
[image]

```
\documentclass[ijoc,nonblindrev]{informs3} % %current default for 
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII 
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,lined, noend]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlFnt{\small}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwIn{Suppose we are given with several parameters} 
      \For{$i \in I$} {   }
    \caption{\scshape Animal microRNAs (miRNAs) regulate gene expression by 
             inhibiting.}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
   \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlFnt{\small}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \KwIn{Another set of inputs} 
    \For{$i \in I$} {}
  \caption{\scshape Here we show that a single miRNA can repress the production of 
           hundreds.}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```