# How to wrap text around an algorithm

Tags: algorithms

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newfloat{algorithm}{t}{lop}
\begin{document}

This text comes before the algorithm. \lipsum[2-4]

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{An algorithm with caption}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require $n \geq 0$
\Ensure $y = x^n$
\State $y \gets 1$
\State $X \gets x$
\State $N \gets n$
\While{$N \neq 0$}
\If{$N$ is even}
    \State $X \gets X \times X$
    \State $N \gets \frac{N}{2}$  \Comment{This is a comment}
\ElsIf{$N$ is odd}
    \State $y \gets y \times X$
    \State $N \gets N - 1$
\EndIf
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

This comes after.  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

I want to wrap text around an `algorithm`. I've tried the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/floating-an-algorithm) but that didn't seem to work. For some reason the text is still not wrapping around the algorithm. [image]

Comment: `algorithm` is a *float*. It's meant to float around, and you purposefully suggest the `[t]`op. If you don't want things to float, then you can review this: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527036/how-to-place-two-algorithms-side-by-side/527045?r=SearchResults&s=2|21.1906#527045 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614400/fit-three-algorithms-in-a-single-page/614406?r=SearchResults&s=1|22.1926#614406